# Google sheets function to get dates from a range

Tags: function, date, google-sheets, filter

Is there a function in google sheets to get a list of dates from a range, given that the range has text and date types.
i tried using the filter formula and is date as following:

`=FILTER(H45:J45, ISDATE())`

This didnt work, but all my search shows that these 2 formulas are my best bet to make this work.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You could try:*

```js
=filter(H45:J45, isdate_strict(H45:J45))
```

Comment: Hey @Osm, Uhh sorry that wasnt me...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
=FILTER(H45:J45, ISTEXT(H45:J45)<>true)
```

## Explanation

This formula `=FILTER(H45:J45, ISTEXT(H45:J45)<>true)` works because it filters a range `(H45:J45)` to include only cells that contain text values. The ISTEXT function checks if a cell contains text, and the <> true part ensures that only cells where the result is not equal to "true" (i.e., cells that do not contain text) are included in the filtered result.

The OP formula `=FILTER(H45:J45, ISDATE())` doesn't work as intended because the `ISDATE` function is not designed to check for the presence of dates in a range. Instead, it checks if a given value is a valid date. Since you didn't specify a value within the `ISDATE` function, it treats the function as if it's checking the entire range `(H45:J45)` for date values, which isn't its intended use.

Comment: so lets assume that in my range there are mixed types of data lets say numbers dates and text, the mentioned formula would include all data types except for text. Is that correct ?

Comment: yes this is correct